# Where does geth download it's data, the actual blockchain state?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

We know that we can sync with current blockchain status with geth, for example, or any other similar things. If I run geth in console I can see

```
...
INFO [11-16|22:27:56.602] Imported new block receipts              count=14  elapsed=92.495ms    number=24590 hash=f24d7d..70e905 age=6y4mo2w  size=4.73KiB
INFO [11-16|22:27:56.654] Imported new block receipts              count=178 elapsed=25.699ms    number=24768 hash=38e6be..9a5fbe age=6y4mo2w  size=64.92KiB
INFO [11-16|22:27:58.507] Imported new block headers               count=2048 elapsed=75.153ms    number=26816 hash=f97a01..8361a4 age=6y4mo2w
INFO [11-16|22:27:58.626] Imported new block headers               count=2048 elapsed=113.496ms   number=28864 hash=5df004..eab322 age=6y4mo2w
INFO [11-16|22:27:58.626] Imported new block receipts              count=39   elapsed=59.524ms    number=24807 hash=2c603d..9e4cd6 age=6y4mo2w  size=13.07KiB
INFO [11-16|22:27:58.638] Imported new block headers               count=128  elapsed=5.576ms     number=28992 hash=d2689c..52a3fb age=6y4mo2w
WARN [11-16|22:27:58.694] Dropping unsynced node during sync       id=c17e0e458a8c095f conn=dyndial addr=3.141.249.97:30303 type=Geth/v1.10.3-stable-...
INFO [11-16|22:27:59.244] Imported new block receipts              count=2048 elapsed=78.460ms    number=26855 hash=146d01..042ed7 age=6y4mo2w  size=738.53KiB
INFO [11-16|22:27:59.321] Imported new block receipts              count=2048 elapsed=66.566ms    number=28903 hash=305580..5cda53 age=6y4mo2w  size=733.11KiB
INFO [11-16|22:27:59.343] Imported new block receipts              count=89   elapsed=21.801ms    number=28992 hash=d2689c..52a3fb age=6y4mo2w  size=32.24KiB
INFO [11-16|22:28:04.446] State sync in progress                   synced=0.16% state=324.34MiB accounts=243,032@57.29MiB slots=1,265,871@254.19MiB codes=4942@12.86MiB eta=4h17m40.665s
...
```

so it means I download the data. But where is this data stored? Does it get pulled directly from the blockchain? Who responds to the requests? How can I become a peer?

Answer (score 0):

Try a dashboard tool, like [Grafana](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13877), to witness it: nodes are peer-to-peer, meaning you download blockes from other node as well as share/upload them to nodes in need (by default, light nodes connect to 100 peers, while full ones to 50 - see https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options for default values and overrides).

The default data folders can be found here (platform dependant) : https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/install-and-build/backup-restore